# When should I mark the copy\movement constructor as deleted in C++? What aspects should be considered?

Tags: c++

When should I mark the copy\movement constructor as deleted in C++? What aspects should be considered? Is there any potential problem that I should be aware of while the copy\movement constructor neither has been deleted nor replaced by a user-defined one? I would appreciate that if you could give a few simple examples including the ones provided by the libc++ or libstdc++.

I have thought and thought about it, but still don't fully understand it. I would be very grateful to have some help with this question.

Answer (score 3):

A type should be non-copyable if copying would be incompatible with the designed intent of the type or if copying would represent an expensive operation or otherwise impact the performance of the type. The obvious case of the former is `unique_ptr`: an object which uniquely owns a specific resource. If you could copy the `unique_ptr`, then you would have two objects that own that resource. That would violate the intent of uniquely owning the resource, so it makes no sense.

Expensive operations would be something like `std::mutex`. It isn't fundamentally unreasonable to want to be able to copy a `mutex`. However, doing so would on many implementations require that the `mutex` heap-allocate (and use shared references) whatever internal OS mutex data structure is used to implement the mutex. That's needlessly expensive; a user who doesn't need to copy the `mutex` is paying for the ability to do so. Therefore instead, if a user want to be able to "copy a mutex", then they can heap-allocate `std::mutex` it and stick it in a `shared_ptr`.